# JSON is not Retrieved When Put on the Server but Does Work on Localhost using XAMPP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm having a problem, my code works in XAMPP. However, it is not working once I put it in the server, I host it with fatcow, it seems that they work json and php 5.2.

I'm using Jquery and Json, two commands I'm using to retrive the data $.getJSON and $.post, I'm using two libraries 
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
jquery.json.js

I have no clue what is the problem, the json encode outputs json data, but my code from js doesn't retrive it doesn't seem that it copies to the array i have with $.getJson. I dont understand, all help will be greatly appretiated.

Comment: did the browser throw an error?

Comment: You will have to post the code you're using to retrieve the JSON from your server for us to have a first look at what could be causing the problem.  Also, you need to report whether there are any javascript errors showing in the browser's error console or debug console?

Comment: Any difference if you use a local copy of jquery on your server? Are the script loaded without error (verified with firebug or sth else)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JSON data is not returned due to the Cross Origin Resource Sharing policy (CORS).

You can solve this problem by:

- Putting the JSON file in the same domain as the Javascript/HTML file that requests it

OR

- By adding the header:

  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

to your JSON file.

[More information on how to add CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/)

[More information on CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Hope that helps :)